# TypeError: [function name] is not a function, in mongoose and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to node.js and mongoose, and I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with the below error.

I make a put request via the following function (the point of the function is to "upvote" a forum post.

```
o.upvote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote')
        .success(function(data){
            post.upvotes += 1;
        });
};
```

That in turn goes to my route:

**index.js (my route)**

```
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
    req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

And below is my model

**Posts.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};
```

In my index.js route, the below error is thrown on the line "req.post.upvote":

> TypeError: req.post.upvote is not a function

Comment: What is `req.post` supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.post` will not be set automatically. You need another middleware to set it, but most likely you want to get it from the DB with the parameter.

```
const Post = mongoose.model("Post");

router.put("/posts/:post/upvote", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.findById(req.params.post, (err, post) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    post.upvote((err, post) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: You also need to set the methods *before* you create the schema in mongoose:

```
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comment: I already have define a parameter earlier in my code called "post", (sorry I didn't include it in my original post).  But when I debug, I am able to see the "post" object correctly.  The issue is that I want to call the "upvote" function defined in my model, but I can't seem to do that. Thanks

Comment: @Flame1845 maybe try moving the `mongoose.schema` call _after_ the you set the `.methods`

Comment: you legend, that fixed it...thanks a lot!  I wasn't aware that I had to do that...I'll keep it in mind for the future!